# Wave file obfuscation

Tags: file, header, format, obfuscation

I have this file here, that is supposed to be a wave audio file, but seems to have some obfuscation applied to it.

The file header is here:

```
00000000   F5 6A E1 65  AB C2 B1 30  F0 62 F1 66  C1 4E D3 03  B7 23 A7 23 .j.e...0.b.f.N...#.#
00000014   A6 23 A5 23  E3 8F A7 23  B7 92 A5 23  A3 23 B7 23  C3 42 D3 42  .#.#...#...#.#.#.B.B
00000028   A7 C3 B1 30  58 DC A7 23  A5 23 A6 23  59 DC 59 DC  A5 23 A5 23  ...0X..#.#.#Y.Y..#.#
0000003C   59 DC 58 DC  A5 23 A7 23  59 DC A5 23  A5 23 5A DC  59 DC A4 23  Y.X..#.#Y..#.#Z.Y..#
00000050   A6 23 5A DC  A6 23 A5 23  59 DC A7 23  A5 23 A7 23  59 DC 58 DC  .#Z..#.#Y..#.#.#Y.X.
00000064   A5 23 A6 23  59 DC 58 DC  A5 23 A7 23  59 DC A5 23  A5 23 5A DC  .#.#Y.X..#.#Y..#.#Z.
00000078   59 DC A4 23  A5 23 5A DC  59 DC A5 23  A5 23 59 DC  59 DC A4 23  Y..#.#Z.Y..#.#Y.Y..#
0000008C   A5 23 5A DC  59 DC A5 23  A5 23 58 DC  59 DC A7 23  A5 23 A7 23  .#Z.Y..#.#X.Y..#.#.#
000000A0   58 DC A7 23  A7 23 A7 23  A6 23 A6 23  59 DC 58 DC  A5 23 A7 23  X..#.#.#.#.#Y.X..#.#
000000B4   58 DC 58 DC  A6 23 A5 23  59 DC 59 DC  A4 23 A5 23  5B DC 59 DC  X.X..#.#Y.Y..#.#[.Y.
000000C8   A4 23 A6 23  A7 23 A7 23  5A DC 58 DC  A2 23 A6 23  5C DC A7 23  .#.#.#.#Z.X..#.#\..#
000000DC   A4 23 59 DC  58 DC A4 23  A7 23 5A DC  A7 23 A4 23  A6 23 59 DC  .#Y.X..#.#Z..#.#.#Y.
000000F0   59 DC A7 23  A5 23 A7 23  59 DC A6 23  A5 23 58 DC  59 DC A5 23  Y..#.#.#Y..#.#X.Y..#
00000104   A5 23 5A DC  59 DC A4 23  A5 23 5A DC  58 DC A4 23  A7 23 59 DC  .#Z.Y..#.#Z.X..#.#Y.
00000118   A6 23 A6 23  5A DC A7 23  A3 23 58 DC  5A DC A6 23  A5 23 A7 23  .#.#Z..#.#X.Z..#.#.#
0000012C   58 DC 58 DC  A7 23 A6 23  A7 23 A7 23  A7 23 59 DC  A7 23 A3 23  X.X..#.#.#.#.#Y..#.#
00000140   A6 23 5C DC  59 DC A1 23  A5 23 5D DC  58 DC A2 23  A7 23 5B DC  .#\.Y..#.#].X..#.#[.
00000154   A7 23 A4 23  A7 23 58 DC  A7 23 A7 23  A7 23 A7 23  A6 23 A6 23  .#.#.#X..#.#.#.#.#.#
00000168   59 DC 5A DC  A6 23 A2 23  A7 23 5D DC  A7 23 A1 23  58 DC 5C DC  Y.Z..#.#.#]..#.#X.\.
0000017C   A5 23 A3 23  59 DC 5B DC  A5 23 A3 23  59 DC 5B DC  A6 23 A3 23  .#.#Y.[..#.#Y.[..#.#
00000190   A7 23 5B DC  58 DC A4 23  A4 23 59 DC  5B DC A5 23  A4 23 59 DC  .#[.X..#.#Y.[..#.#Y.
000001A4   59 DC A6 23  A5 23 58 DC  58 DC A6 23  A7 23 A7 23  A7 23 A7 23  Y..#.#X.X..#.#.#.#.#
000001B8   58 DC 58 DC  A4 23 A5 23  5A DC 5A DC  A4 23 A4 23  5A DC 59 DC  X.X..#.#Z.Z..#.#Z.Y.
000001CC   A5 23 A6 23  58 DC 58 DC  A7 23 A6 23  A6 23 58 DC  58 DC A6 23  .#.#X.X..#.#.#X.X..#
000001E0   A6 23 58 DC  59 DC A6 23  A5 23 58 DC  59 DC A6 23  A5 23 59 DC  .#X.Y..#.#X.Y..#.#Y.
000001F4   58 DC A5 23  58 DC A7 23  A5 23 58 DC  18 83 E4 7C  E4 7C 1A 83  X..#X..#.#X....|.|..
```

Any suggestions where else it would be appropriate to ask?

Comment: Maybe try the [Reverse Engineering](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/) site?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file is xored by key `0xA7 0x23`. After xoring the very first bytes, the header looks like this:

`52 49 46 46 0C E1 16 13 57 41 56 45 66 6D 74 20  RIFF.á..WAVEfmt`

So mostly like correct wave header.